# In Django authentication for Corporate company via Active Directory, option available if LDAP is not installed

Tags: python, django

Developing application with Django for Corporate company and user need to authenticated based AD, what if LDAP has not installed then what could be available options to authenticate users

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe).

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I asked for scenario, i don't thinks so code will help here.